# JSON response not displaying on view with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am having a problem displaying a JSON response on web page using Angularjs, on DevTools i can see that the GET request work great and can grab all data, but when it comes to dislaying it on a list all i got is dots .

My controller :

```
 budgetApp.controller('DepensesListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
        function DepensesListCtrl($scope, $http) {
            $scope.depenses = [];

            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/depenses', {withCredentials: true}).success(function(data) {
                $scope.depenses = data;
            });
```

Using ng-repeat :

```
<div >
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>depenses Page</h1>   
    </div>
    <ul ng-repeat="depense in depenses">
        <li>{{depense.depname}}</li>
        <li>{{depense.depcat}} </li>
    </ul>
```

Result : 
[image]

Response JSON :
[image]

I tried debuging with alerts, i figured out that my depenses array allways give **undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is an object that has a property `Depense` that contains the  array you want to repeat

Try:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/depenses', {withCredentials: true}).success(function(data) {
       $scope.depenses = data.Depense;
                           // ^^^ property that contains array
});
```

OR:

```
<ul ng-repeat="depense in depenses.Depense">
```